# Application.OpenForms as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible bind Application.OpenForms as ListBox.DataSource?
I need fill ListBox control by the names of currently open forms.

Comment: have you actually tried it?

Comment: yes, Application.OpenForms isn't implement IList or IListSource interfaces.

Comment: I'm using NET 2.0, so no LINQ here.

Comment: then you'll need to iterate through the collection in a conventional way. In the end it's just an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  listBox1.DataSource = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToList();
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
}
```

Here is the solution without LINQ:

```
//Use ArrayList instead
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  listBox1.DataSource = new System.Collections.ArrayList(Application.OpenForms);
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
}
```